# NSRunningApplication activateWithOptions method behavior change with Big Sur

Tags: macos, appkit, macos-big-sur

I am using an application to select windows on MacOS Big Sur. (I have a slight hand tremor that causes me to often miss the intended target with mouse clicks.)

The app:

- uses the AppKit "Accessibility for macOS" API to select windows. It calls the `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue` function to set the attribute `NSAccessibilityMainAttribute` to bring a particular window to the front **and then**
- calls `NSRunningAppplication`'s method `activateWithOptions:` passing `NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps` to activate the app associated with that window.

Unfortunately, I see a behavior change under Big Sur. Specifically, imagine I have two apps open, each with two windows:

- AppX has windows:

  - X1 covering left half of my screen
  - X2 covering the right half of my screen
- AppY has windows:

  - Y1 covering the left half of my screen
  - Y2 covering the right half of my screen

Starting with both X1 and X2 visible (on top):

- **before Big Sur** I could select window **Y2** which would making **AppY** the current app and leave me with windows **X1** and **Y2** visible
- **since upgrading to Big Sur** when I select window **Y2**, the call to `activateWithOptions:` brings all of application **AppY**'s windows forwards, showing only **Y1** and **Y2**.

The same thing happens in the reverse situation (starting with **Y1** and **Y2** visible (on top), then trying to bring **X1** forward and still see **Y2**).

The documentation for `NSRunningApplication`'s `activateWithOptions:` method says:

> By default, activation brings only the main and key windows forward. If you specify NSApplicationActivateAllWindows, all of the application's windows are brought forward." My application is not specifying NSApplicationActivateAllWindows.

Any suggestions on how the app *should* be handling this? (It's perfectly fine if you say, "The app is already doing the right thing," but I'd love to know if there is a reasonable work-around.)

[Aside: I'd also welcome any tips on the best way to bring this to Apple's attention.]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Seems like a bug in Big Sur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just managed to make my app work correctly again using the following code. It uses deprecated functions (as of 10.9) so I don't expect those functions to disappear soon. Not ideal, but at least it does not result in a weird user experience.

```
- (OSStatus)makeApplicationFront:(NSRunningApplication*)application
{
    if(!application || application.processIdentifier == -1) {
        return procNotFound; // Previous front most application is nil or does not have a process identifier.
    }
    ProcessSerialNumber process;
    OSStatus error = GetProcessForPID(application.processIdentifier, &process); // Deprecated, but replacement (NSRunningApplication:activateWithOptions:] does not work properly on Big Sur.
    if(error) {
        return error; // Process could not be obtained. Evaluate error (e.g. using osstatus.com) to understand why.
    }
    return SetFrontProcessWithOptions(&process, kSetFrontProcessFrontWindowOnly); // Deprecated, but replacement (NSRunningApplication:activateWithOptions:] does not work properly on Big Sur.
}
```

Hope it also helps you.

Comment: Thank you, @niels-mouthaan! That is very useful indeed. I may try to stub in some similar code to try to restore my functionality…while I wait for Apple to acknowledge and correct their problem.

Comment: just an update: I was able to successfully incorporate something like the code you suggested into the app I was using. I hope to be able to use this work-around until Apple actually fixes the API they broke.

Comment: Great to hear, and I agree, although I haven't received feedback on my bug report yet.